# Is it possible to add additional zeros with AngularJS $formatters? (or in any possible way, with number input?)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, input, number-formatting

I want to write AngularJS directive which adds zeros to number in input, even if they are not necessary. I have:

```
<input type="number" step="0.1">
```

And even it has value `1`, I want to display it as `1.0`. And of course if step is `0.01`, it should always be displayed as `1.00`. Crux of the matter is that, if it is possible, I want to use `number` input instead of `text` (built-in HTML validation, mobile devices keyboard etc..). So I thought about AngularJS formatters (simple example to just do it for hard-coded values):

```
ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
    return Number((value + 0.00001).toFixed(3));
});
```

And it didn't work, it lost unnecessary zeros. And, because `input` has type `number`, I can not return `String` from formatter. I have made a plunk with my try: [Plunker: Directive which adds additional zeros](https://plnkr.co/edit/YklnHLQmrGTlFGnXZGM7?p=preview).
T think it should be possible in some way (maybe without Angular?), because if I have hard-coded:

```
<input type="number" value="3.000">
```

It displays `3.000` in input. Even if I open Developer Console on my Plunk I am able to do this:

```
document.querySelector('#with-directive').value = '33.0'
```

And it displays `33.0` (DOM manipulation is of course a solution to solve this problem, but I think it can lead to code, which is not easy to maintain and I want to avoid it if possible)
Am I right, is it possible to do it? I would be very grateful if anybody decides to help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: you can set an input[type=number] with a string (as you did in your querySelector-based code),  so just change "Number" to "String" in your 2nd code box. in fact, input.value will always be a string for non-:checked inputs

Comment: @dandavis I dont think so, if I do: `return String((value + 0.00001).toFixed(3));` I got http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/ngModel/numfmt?p0=NaN, even if I explicitly wrote `return String('2');` I got `Expected '2' to be a number` error, which is weird - as you said with `querySelector().value` it can be string, but it can't with ng-model for some reasons which I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use type `tel` instead of number. Because ios doesn't support type `number` and on the other side if you use type `tel` then your output is a string.
You have to adust your `$formatter` like that.

```
ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
    return (parseInt(value)).toFixed(3);
 });
```

Comment: It looks like I have to use `document.querySelector(...)`, but I accept your answer as the closest, thanks for help!